# Template struct violates ODR with itself

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, one-definition-rule

for the first time today i compiled my code base with link time optimizations turned on with gcc 5.1 and i am getting bizarre ODR warnings :

```
Functor.h:67:8: warning: type 'struct Func' violates one definition rule [-Wodr]
    class Func : public FuncBase
Functor.h:67:8: note: a different type is defined in another translation unit
    class Func : public FuncBase
```

The code looks like that:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Functor
{
    class FuncBase : NonCopyable
    {
        public:
            FuncBase() {
            }
            virtual ~FuncBase() {
            }
            virtual R apply(Args...) = 0;
    };
    template<typename T>
    class Func : public FuncBase
    {
        public:
            Func(const T &t) : f(t) {
            }
            virtual ~Func() {
            }
            virtual R apply(Args... args) override {
                return f(args...);
            }
        private:
            T f;
    };
    /* ... */

    std::shared_ptr<FuncBase> func;
    public:
    template<typename T>
    Functor(const T &t) : func(new Func<T>(t)) {
    }


};
```

As you can see, Func conflicts with itself.

How gcc can find an ODR problem in a template class ? 
I don't understand ODR completely myself but i feel that there should be 'multiple declaration of' errors instead.

Note : the member f seems to be the source of the problem :

```
Functor.h:81:6: note: a field of same name but different type is defined in another translation unit
T f;
```

Note 2: 
The problem seems only arise when i construct a Functor in a destructor:

```
UniformBuffer.h:40:26: note: type name 'DynamicBuffer::Data::~Data(int)::{lambda()#1}' should match type name 'DynamicBuffer::Data::~Data()::{lambda()#1}'
  Async([=]() {
UniformBuffer.h:40:26: note: the incompatible type is defined here
  Async([=]() {
```

With Async looking like this :

```
void Async(const Functor<void> &f) {
   // ....
}
```

Wierdly the functor is not declared in the destructor no warning are generated. i feel like gcc is generating 2 version of these causing conflicts.

Comment: difficult to check here without a complete example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: How do you use the classes? How and where do you instantiate these classes? Can you perhaps try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Did you protect the template header with include guards (or `#pragma once` if you prefer)

Comment: Yes, the file has include guards.

Comment: I am trying to find a minimal example.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well, but the class is not templated. It reports: `note: a type with different alignment is defined in another translation unit`. Version is `gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04)` and `GNU gold (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu 2.24) 1.11`. Can't see any way alignment would have been specified!

Comment: Oops, actually, version is `gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)` and `GNU gold (GNU Binutils 2.25.1) 1.11`.

Comment: Nevermind.. had a hidden #pragma pack(n) in a header file without a matching #pragma pack() to reset it! Forgot about that one...

Comment: @nonsensickle I rolled back your edit because Jetski S-type's comment is not the OP's. There is no indication that the cause or solution is the same. That aside, even if it were the OP's, answers belong in the answer box, not in the question. It would've been okay to post an answer yourself in that case (perhaps marked Community Wiki).

Comment: @hvd Ok, but the answer is not mine and I did not want to take it. I was in a rush and didn't notice that it was not OP's comment, sorry. I'd be happy for you to post the answer, if you thought that was correct. However, reading it again I've noticed that Jetski S-type's comments are a follow up question and answer that are probably better to split out from here.